# Code Doesn't Work When on Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [Readmore.js](http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/) on my website to shorten text.

```
<div id="TEST">THIS IS A TEST THIS IS A TEST THIS IS A TEST</div>

     <script>
     $('#TEST').readmore({
         speed: 250,
         maxHeight: 10,
         moreLink: '<a href="#" style="font-size:14px;color:#007096">Read More</a>',
         lessLink: '<a href="#" style="font-size:14px;color:#007096">Read Less</a>'
     });
     </script>
```

For some reason if I take this code and paste it directly on my page, it executes just fine. However, if I place this EXACT same code verbatim on a bootstrap 3 modal, it doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: You can remove `THIS IS A TEST`. It's redundant code that we don't need to see.

Comment: Add the part with the modal as well

Answer (score 0):

I suggest attaching `readmore` function when the modal actually gets showed, using `show.bs.modal` event.
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
       $('#test').readmore({
             // your options here...
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply- still no luck. If I use a similar plugin, it works, so maybe it's just specific to Readmore.js. I'll probably keep searching for a plugin that suits my needs or write my own. Thanks!